# Blender basic cube renders grey

Tags: rendering

I have read pretty much all the articles available on this problem but I can't find a solution. Or at least all that a true beginner like me can undersand.
I have Blender 2.82a and when I go for rendering I just have a grey image, even with the cube provided by Blender, In both Eevee and Cycles renders.

What am I missing? all is visible and selected for rendering, clipping is untouched, camera and light active. What else?

I would like to use Cycles. 
P.S. Long rendering times apart, is it ok for a MacBook Pro Retina Late 2013?

Many Many thanks for your help

Comment: Hello :). Please add some images to your post, to better illustrate the issue. You can also [share the .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).